# How to hold multiple values in xCP page?

Tags: java, arrays, json, documentum, xcp2.x

One of my dataservice is returning a string as response. The dataservice can be invoked multiple times before moving to the next page. I need to hold the string that I am getting as a response (in array or json) and pass it to another dataservice in the next page. Thanks in advance.